# Java Runtime.getRuntime() and Process Builder unable to execute perl script with arguments

Tags: java, perl, process, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I am trying to call a Perl script from a Java program using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. The Perl script has multiple arguments.

For example:

```
abc.pl -dt 64 -dir C:\Projects\xyz -name pqr -args 'X24 X56'
```

The Perl program is being executed but not receiving all the arguments. This causes the script to throw an error. I have tried the following variations:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("abc.pl -dt 64 -dir C:\\Projects\\xyz -name pqr -args 'X24 X56'");

Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"abc.pl","-dt 64","-dir C:\\Projects\\xyz","-name pqr","-args 'X24 X56'"});

Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"abc.pl","-dt","64","-dir","C:\\Projects\\xyz","-name","pqr","-args","'X24 X56'"});

ProcessBuilder p4 = new ProcessBuilder("abc.pl -dt 64 -dir C:\\Projects\\xyz -name pqr -args 'X24 X56'");
    p4.start();

List<String> cmds = new ArrayList<>();
cmds.add("abc.pl");
cmds.add("-dt 64");
cmds.add("-dir C:\\Projects\\xyz");
cmds.add("-name pqr");
cmds.add("-args 'X24 X56'");
ProcessBuilder p5 = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
p5.start();

List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();
cmd.add("abc.pl");
cmd.add("-dt");
cmd.add("64");
cmd.add("-dir");
cmd.add("C:\\Projects\\xyz");
cmd.add("-name");
cmd.add("pqr");
cmd.add("-args");
cmd.add("'X24 X56'");
ProcessBuilder p6 = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
p6.start();
```

The command works perfectly fine on a terminal.

I also tried hard-coding the command in a bash script. When I called the script using `Runtime.getRuntime()` it worked fine. But the command will be generated by my program and can vary, so this isn't a permanent solution.

Comment: Does your Perl program give the same error for all of those different methods? Your Perl program is presumably using `Getopt::Long`; I suggest you add some code to dump the contents of `@ARGV` before the call to `GetOptions` modifies it so that you can see what is actually being passed.

Comment: Try changing  `"'X24 X56'"` in the third call to `"X24 X56"`

Comment: Actually the script is throwing an exit code which on inspection revealed that some arguments are missing thats why it throws that particular code. And the script is part of a legacy code and I cant modify it. The command itself works on the terminal and I am fetching it from a db so cant modify that either.

Comment: Can't you make a temporary copy and modiffy that? Or write a dummy program that just dumps `@ARGV` and stops?

Comment: Well I thought about that but the script is embedded in the environment and using its dependencies so making a temporary copy of it wont work. And the arguments will change according to the state of the program and I have to call the script multiple times. So essentially I would have to create a temporary script with the command in it on runtime with all the arguments and then destroy it after execution. But that doesnt really seem like a good way

Comment: We're just trying to debug here. You can write a three-line Perl program that just dumps `@ARGV` and call it using each of your techniques to see exactly what is being passed.

Comment: P3 with @Borodin's change would be correct on Unix, so you should try that first. This is harder than it should be because Windows programs are invoked with a single argument string, not argument arrays like on Unix. This means that Java needs to map your multiple arguments into a single string, and then Perl needs to parse them out from the single string back into multiple arguments. There is no standard way of doing this, and when you e.g. have nested literal quotes (which you don't) two environments may have literally no way of passing them without loss. Quite a mess.

Comment: Re "*The Perl program is being executed but not receiving all the arguments.*", This seems extremely unlikely. How did you determine this? Which arguments were received? It's clear you are receiving incorrect arguments (because you combine them, or added quotes), but missing arguments? I think you've misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: Could be a bad association, though. But I'll wait for you to prove that's the problem by answering my questions before I spend time on that.

Comment: @that other guy, Not so! There is a standard format: [`CommandLineToArgv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @ikegami As to why i believe there are missing arguments well thats because the script was giving an exit code. The same for all the above formats. Now upon looking into the script i found 3 conditions for that exit code: one is if i passed 'help' as an argument, second if the arguments i passed are wrong and result couldn't be obtained but it works on terminal so that shouldn't be the case and third if the arguments are incomplete

Comment: Ok, so you have no reason to believe it's not receiving arguments, leaving only your errors. Just remove the single quotes form p3 or p6, as mentioned above.

Comment: It started working without the single quotes in both p3 and p6. But the command was being fetched from a db and manipulated by the program. I would have to see why does it work in terminal. But i can work ahead now. Thanks

Comment: What you call your "terminal" appears to be a unix shell. Java surely uses `cmd` on Windows. If you want to run a `sh` command, you will need to run `sh`.